# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable even though iterator was removed

Tags: python, iterator, calculator, typeerror

This is a training version of Calculator, for some reason I am getting the error:

```
      File "C:/Users/stazc/PycharmProjects/project00/Calculator.py", line 54, in calculate
    print(sum(self.numY,self.numX))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The interesting part is that I am not using the iterator here, even though I wanted to. I executed the code before and run just fine the added some code for looping and it gave this error. Now the looping part is in comments so it should not affect the code although it is still giving me the same error!!

```
class Calculator:
    numX = 0
    numY = 0
    __sign = ''

    def __init__(self):
        pass
        # self.numX = x
        # self.numY = y
        # self.__sign = sign

    def set_key_values(self):
        print("Input numbers and then symbol")
        self.numX = int(input("X: "))
        self.__sign = input("Input symbol: ")
        self.numY = int(input("Y: "))

    #functions
    def sum(self,numX, numY):
        return numX+numY

    def minus(self,numX, numY):
        return numX-numY

    def mult(self,numX, numY):
        return numX*numY

    def divide(self,numX, numY):
        return numX/numY

    #setters
    def set_x(self,x):
        self.numX = x

    def set_y(self,y):
        self.numY = y

    def set_sign(self,sign):
        self.__sign = sign
    numX = numX
    #getters

    def get_x(self):
        return self.numX

    def get_y(self):
        return self.numY

    def get_sign(self):
        return self.__sign

    def calculate(self):
        if self.__sign == '+':
            print(sum(self.numY,self.numX))
        elif self.__sign == '-':
            print(self.minus(self.numX,self.numY))
        elif self.__sign == '*':
            print(self.mult(self.numX,self.numY))
        elif self.__sign == '/':
            print(self.divide(self.numX,self.numY))
        else:
            print('Incorrect Input, try again!')


c = Calculator()
c.set_key_values()
c.calculate()
```

Here I tried to add a loop that you can keep adding stuff but this error made my code stop working completely and can't see why?

```
#
# loop = input("Keep Going? y/n")
# cont = True
# if loop[0] == 'y':
#     cont = True
# else:
#     cont = False
#
# while cont:
#     c = Calculator()
#     c.set_key_values()
#     c.calculate()
# else:
#     quit()
#
```

Comment: I am using a lot of functions because I want to practice superclasses and classes and function calling.

Comment: You forgot `self.`

Comment: The first parameter of [`sum(iterable[, start])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) expects a iterable, and an `int` isn't an iterable. Hence the error. It appears you are meaning to use your `self.sum` method and not the built-in python method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get this error:

```
print(sum(self.numY,self.numX))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Is because you are using Pythons built-in [`sum(iterable[, start])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) method. And the first parameter it takes expects an iterable. Instead you will want to use your defined method `self.sum` that belongs to your `Calculator` class.

```
print(self.sum(self.numY,self.numX))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Python so I would have never noticed that xD

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sum()` with `self.sum()` where you get your error.
You want to do this because python's version is different from yours and needs an iterable as first argument to work. Everything in your calculator is using the self function instead of the python too so thats another reason.

Comment: You should expand on this answer, and include why he should replace it. It would go a long way towards helping future readers understand why the issue exists in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never noticed!

Comment: Can you upvote my answer please since it helped you :)